# How to filter a vector and return a vector of pointer to vector elements

Tags: c++, stdvector

When filtering vectors with primitive data types I usually do this:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v2;
std::copy_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2),
         [](int const& x) { return criterion(x); } );
```

Now I have a vector with huge objects which are very costly to copy. I want to have a list of pointers (std::vector) to specific elements of my original vector, depending on whether they meet a predicate condition or not.

My first idea would be creating this kind of vector by myself, fill it with pointers to all the elements and filter the elements into a third vector by using copy_if. Another idea would be using a loop doing this. What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I use references instead of pointers?

Comment: `Should I use references instead of pointers?`: You simply can't because references by nature aren't copyable and STL containers require that their elements must be copyable.

Comment: Just make v2 an index (std::vector<std::size_t>) to elements in v1.

Comment: I would hesitate to put objects in a vector that you don't want copied.  You could start with a vector of (smart) pointers, which can be copied to your filtered vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw pointers are fine for non-owning semantics, though you must be able to guarantee they stay valid <=> the vector won't be reallocated.

Indices into the vector are more robust, they only go stale if the object changes position / is removed.

Anyway, if the objects are that expensive to copy, are they also expensive to move? Consider `std::unique_ptr` and heap-allocating them then (`std::shared_ptr` is probably much too heavy-weight still, even if you use `std::make_shared`).

If you only need the sequence once (or calculating the predicate is cheap and there's an acceptable ratio of selected to non-selected eleents), you might consider passing a custom iterator instead, which does the filtering on-the-fly. (See: [`boost::filter_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) for example)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
std::vector<T> vector; // T is a large object
// filling the vector...
std::vector<const T *> matched;
for (const T& ref: vector) if (criterion(ref))
    matched.push_back(static_cast<const T *>(&ref));
```

**but** you need to be aware that these pointers will be fresh unless you append any element to the vector, std::vector may reallocate memory regions when needed and then all of your pointers in matched container would be invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the vector...keep a count variable initialized to zero.

when criterion is met on a element,

1) swap it with an element at index count.

2) Increment the count.

In the end erase all elements from count in the vector.

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
int count =0;
for(itr = v1.begin(); itr !=v1.end(); itr++)
{

if(criterion(*itr))
{
  std::iter_swap(v1.begin()+count,itr);
  count++;
}

}

//delete
vec.erase(v1.begin() + count, v1.end());
```